# Solr | Partial Document Updates Doesn't work on Child Nested Document

Tags: solr, lucene, updates

I am following this link: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/partial-document-updates.html to modify the childDocument. Below is the doc I created.

```
{
  "id":"111a",
  "filterId":2222,
  "filterName":"filterName1",
  "filterIdName":"idName1",
  "filterValueId":6666,
  "filterValue":"value1",
  "filterIdValue":[
      {
        "id":"111b",
        "filterId":2223,
        "filterName":"filterName2",
        "filterIdName":"idName2",
        "filterValueId":6667,
        "filterValue":"value2",
        "filterIdValue":"idValue"
      },
      {
        "id":"111c",
        "filterId":2224,
        "filterName":"filterName3",
        "filterIdName":"idName3",
        "filterValueId":6668,
        "filterValue":"value3",
        "filterIdValue":"idValue"
      }
  ]
}
```

Below is what I want to update the filterName of child 111c to from "filterName3" to "filterName4"

```
{
  "id":"111c",
  "_root_": "111a",
  "filterName": {"set": "filter"}
}
```

And I received this error

**Did not find child ID 111c in parent ID 111a**

I use this query to check the parent and child relationship of this doc: q.alt=filterValueId:6666&fl=filterId,filterIdValue,filterValueId,id,[child]

```
"docs": [
{
"filterId": 2222,
"filterValueId": 6666,
"id": "111a",
"_childDocuments_": [
{
"filterId": 2223,
"filterIdValue": "idValue",
"filterValueId": 6667,
"id": "111b"
},
{
"filterId": 2224,
"filterIdValue": "idValue",
"filterValueId": 6668,
"id": "111c"
}
]
}
]
```

I believe that id:111c is in id:111a, but why Solr said it's not? Any suggestion?